# USB drive not in my boot list, cannot boot from usb

Tags: boot, usb

my problem is very simple. Although I can use my flash drive to move files, I am not able to boot from it. Actually, usb drive is not even listed in my bootable device list (along with cd, hdd) in the BIOS. How can I fix this in order to be able to boot from it ?

Comment: Could you post a snapshot of the Boot To category in the BIOS? Is your BIOS the latest version? What model is your computer and what version is your BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it bootable first. You can write a bootable image file to your drive or install GRUB2 on it and use GRUB2 to boot an ISO file from the USB storage.

If you don't know where to start, you can take a look at [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to install GRUB2 and configure it to boot your ISO file from a GUI

Comment: Not entirely true. The "bootable" bit, yes, but the question says the device doesn't appear with CD etc so I would assume BIOS doesn't show device. Check your BIOS to see if there is another option to enable booting to USB. Your BIOS might not be capable of booting to USB. If it can't then you won't be able to boot to USB without a stub-booter via CD. You might as well put your files on CD in that case.

Comment: YES, the BIOS doesn't show the usb device. That's what my question refers to .

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS is the latest version (go to your computer manufacturer's site to download) and still doesn't have the option, then you can follow this method:

I'm assuming your computer has an optical drive, and you have a blank CD.

1. Download [PloP Boot Manager image](http://download.plop.at/files/bootmngr/plpbt-5.0.14.zip)
2. Use any iso burning software to burn the Boot Manager iso to the blank CD. The iso is located at the root of the zip file and it is named plpbt.iso.
3. Enter your BIOS and set it to boot from the optical drive. Insert your CD and reboot, then from there you can boot from the USB.

[Source.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Boot-from-usb-on-an-old-pc-without-modding-the-BIO/) [Demonstration.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-plop-boot-manager-usb-boot)